# Invalid preceding regular expression error given by sed

Tags: sed, grep

I'm part of a rotating team that manages a lot of websites, and we inherited some particularly bad code for one website that we're in the process of completely redesigning. Horrifically enough, there are links on the development server that lead you to the live server and to old domains and a lot of other terrible, terrible things.

I've been trying to write a grep/sed command to replace all of these links with the user-defined php function full_link that we use across our websites now to prevent all the linking to different places. So (using a placeholder for our domain) instead of writing `http://www.place.com/foo/bar`, you'd write `<?php echo full_link('foo/bar'); ?>` and it will work when we move it from one server to another.

Here's what I got:

```
grep -v 'echo' * -r -P | grep "(?<=<a href=['\"])(http:\/\/foo\.bar\.net\/|10\.41\.6\.118\/|http:\/\/foo2\.bar\.net\/)([^<]*?)(?=['\"])" -P | sed -r "s@(?<=<a href=['\"])(http://foo\.bar\.net/|10\.41\.6\.118/|http://foo2\.bar\.net/)([^<]*?)(?=['\"])@<?php echo full_link('\2'); ?>@gpw output"
```

(If you're wondering about the first grep or the `[^<]`, they're both just a basic attempt to keep from putting php tags inside existing php tags. Since it's just a first pass to make manual editing less full of copy-pasting links and getting redirected to the wrong server, it doesn't need to be perfect, but I am open to better ways to do that.)

I've got the grep statements working and picking up what I want them to get, but when I add the sed to the end, this is what happens:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 159: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

From what research I've done, it seems like I probably escaped something in my sed statement incorrectly, and I've tried a number of things, but it only ever gives me the same message pointing to one of the last few characters of the expression.

Comment: This kind of thing is usually easier with Perl

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed "s.http://[^/]*/.<?php echo full_link('.;s/$/'); ?>/"
```

- look for `http://[^/]*/`
- replace with `<?php echo full_link('`
- look for `$`
- replace with `'); ?>`

Comment: @user2319752. Note that this relies on an alternate character '.' to delimit the search pattern from the replace pattern. While '/' is the stnd separator char (because, ??? I don't know, its visible?), but most sed allow using other chars, what ever the first char right after the `s` is, you often see '|' and '@' as alternates. Some seds require that you escape the first use of an alternate char, so you might need `"s\.http://...` ... Good luck to all.

Comment: Yeah, I was using @ as the delimiter because it was one that wasn't anywhere in the search or replace pattern. And I really appreciate the streamlining, but I originally separated out the different possible urls because I don't want it to replace outside links, and one of the kinds of links I have to replace for is just an ip address without any `http://`.

Comment: Also, looking at it again, any `a` tags won't place the end of the link at the end of the string, so `$` probably isn't the best search. While putting the rest of a line in the function wouldn't break anything (unless there's php further along), it's really not a particularly nice solution.