# Wallbase script error file cookies not found and sed error

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am trying to use the following script :  https://github.com/sevensins/Wallbase-Downloader for wallpapers but I got the following errors :

```
Cannot open cookies file ‘cookies.txt’: No such file or directory
sed: 1: "s .\{29\} ": unterminated substitute in regular expression
Any idea how to solve this ?
```

Comment: Open an issue so the author can fix it. https://github.com/sevensins/Wallbase-Downloader/issues

Answer (score 0):

[As shellter says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226857/invalid-preceding-regular-expression-error-given-by-sed/16227613#comment23211629_16227613)

> Some seds require that you escape the first use of an alternate char

So might need to change from this

```sh
sed  's .\{29\}  '
```

To

```sh
sed  's\ .\{29\}  '
```

Comment: sed: 1: "s\ .\{29\} ": substitute pattern can not be delimited by newline or backslash